# How to tell IIS to ignore data after file reference in URI without using "?" or "#" mark

Tags: iis-7.5, uri

Suppose I have static client-side processed HTML file accessible at

```
http://www.example.com/File.html
```

I would like to append additional data after `File.html`. I know I can use `?` but is there any other way so default IIS behaviour would ignore it? Like:

```
http://www.example.com/File.html/Data
```

If I try to access this URL I get a 404 from IIS. This on the other hand naturally works:

```
http://www.example.com/File.html?Data
```

### Question

Is there any way I can use static files on IIS in this way but avoid using `?` or "#"?

### Note

I would also like to avoid IIS configuraiton changes so my files can easily be deployed on the cloud where I can't directly control web server.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? This sounds like you are having an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Nothing particular but as I'm using static server pages that carry client-side-only functionality it seems odd to provide "?" query data that's intended for server processing (primarily). "#" is used for in-page navigation. I would simply like to provide some way to exclude server from the picture so I can process additional data on the client.